# MYSQL item in select value where value is enum

Tags: mysql

I have some hard time with a select, i  think i used in past but i cant remember where.

```
SELECT * FROM tableX WHERE id in ( select ids from tableY );
```

in tableY i have: (ids is a string field with multiple ids separated by comma)

```
ids,...other fields
'1,2,3',...
'1',....
```

Anyone can help with a suggestion ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution on google ...

```
SELECT * FROM tableX 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ids) FROM tableY WHERE ...))
```

Comment: The moral of this story is to avoid commalists.